# Create ARReferenceObject manually from a point cloud

Tags: ios, swift, object-detection, arkit, point-clouds

My idea is to take a point cloud (e.g. a xyz file) and create a `ARReferenceObject` out of it and use that to do object detection. So instead of scanning the object first and use the created object reference I want use my own point cloud to do object detection with ARKit 2.0.

The Apple documentation has something on `rawFeaturePoints` which is a `ARPointCloud`. I saw that `ARPointCloud` has a property called `points` which is a `vector_float3` array which is read only unfortunately. I could not find a way of creating the `ARReferenceObject` manually so I tried the source code from the example [Scanning and Detecting 3D Objects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects).

I scanned a 3D object and exported the generated `.arobject` file which is a zip archive. After unpacking I tinkered with the `trackingData.cv3dmap` but gave up. Looks like a proprietary file format and I'm not that much into reverse engineering the format.

Now my question would be if thereis another solution to create either the `.arobject` files or the `ARReferenceObject` from my own point cloud? Or perhaps there is a totally better way to do object detection based on a already available point cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

Per Apple engineers at WWDC18, object scanning is about much more than just the feature points. `ARReferenceObject` exposes a feature point array in order to provide a representation of the scan results that you can visualize and reason about, but that’s just a slice of the data ARKit saves in a reference object and uses to recognize one. And as far as Apple has indicated publicly, that data and the means to generate it remain proprietary.

(Also, there’s no practical difference between creating an `ARReferenceObject` and creating an `.arobject` file — the latter is essentially the serialized binary version of the former.)